# GASにおけるformタグaction属性の自動指定

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

[GoogleAppsScriptとhtmlでアンケートフォームを作成し、回答をスプレッドシートに記録](https://productivityresearch.net/programing/116/)しています。

index.htmlに記載するformタグaction属性ですが、

```
<form method="post" name="form1" action="$フォームURL$">
```

GASはデプロイするとURLが変わるため、デプロイの度にURLをコピペしなければいけません。
その手間（というほどでもないですが）を解消できないかなと思い、質問させていただきました。

action=""としてしまい、index.html内に以下のように記載すれば良いのでは？と考えたのですが、

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function(){
    document.form1.actions = location.href;
  }
</script>
```

コンソールで確認したところ、全く異なるURLが取得されてしまいました。

**GASをデプロイする度にformタグaction属性を修正しなくても良い方法がありましたら、教えていただきたいです。**
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 例えば、こちらの情報はお役に立ちますか？ https://qiita.com/tanaike/items/060feaf0cc1944002172

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます‼趣旨は同じなので、内容確認してみます。